# Implementing Loops from Pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, loops, implementation

I was wondering if anyone could suggest to me how to implement this loop in the following pseudocode:

> **8: loop**
>   9: while f[0] = 0 do
>   10: for i = 1 to N do
>   11: f[i ¡ 1] = f[i]
>   12: c[N + 1 - i] = c[N - i]
>   13: end for
>   14: f[N] = 0
>   15: c[0] = 0
>   16: k = k + 1
>   17: end while
>   18: if deg(f) = 0 then
>   19: goto Step 32
>   20: end if
>   ......... ...... ....
>   **31: end loop**

My question is how I should implement the loop that starts on line 8 and ends on 31; I am comfortable with the statements between lines 8 to 31, but what kind of loop do I use on line 8, and what conditions do I give for the loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language? That looks like an infinite loop to me, you can use whatever loop construct you want.  Just make sure you have a way to do step 19.

Comment: I'm using Java, @jldupont, well it's for my university project, so yes homework in a way :-)

Comment: @Neville: then may I suggest you add the relevant `homework` tag next time?

Comment: @Neville: no probs! Have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an infinite loop. No conditions, just loop forever. The only way out is to get to step 19. In C-like languages you can write that as `while (true)` or `for (;;)`:

```
for (;;) {
    // ...

    if (deg(f) == 0) {
        goto afterLoop;
    }

    // ...
}

afterLoop:
// ...
```

`goto` is frowned upon, though. It'd be better to replace `goto Step 32` with a `break` statement, which exits a loop immediately:

```
for (;;) {
    // ...

    if (deg(f) == 0) {
        break;
    }

    // ...
}
```

For what it's worth, if you didn't have steps 21-30 you could use a do/while loop, where the loop condition goes at the bottom of the loop instead of the top:

```
do {
    // ...
}
while (deg(f) != 0);
```

That would work if lines 18-20 were the final lines in the loop. Since they're not, it looks like option #2 is the one to go with.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i had no idea it's an infinite loop, I knew I had to break out of it, i think I'll just implement it with an infinite for loop. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to write pseudocode in such detail, you might as well write in the target language. Pseudocode should be a much broader brush - something like this (not related to your code):

```
for each bank account
   check balance as of last month
   if balance greater than promotion limit
      send out valued customer pack
   endif
endfor
```